# Unable to add index on multiple fields in a table --INNODB

Tags: mysql, performance

```
select
    *
from
    A
where
    a = 1755
    and
    b = 11
    and
    c = 50
    and
    d = 11
    and
    response != '';

create index idx_test on A (a, b, c, d, response );
```

While adding index got an error

> Error Code: 1071. Specified key was too long; max key length is 3072 bytes

---

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS A;

CREATE TABLE A (
    id       int unsigned           NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    a        int unsigned           NOT NULL,
    b        int unsigned  DEFAULT      NULL,
    c        int unsigned           NOT NULL,
    d        int unsigned           NOT NULL,
    response varchar(5000) DEFAULT      NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY (id)

) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: Please post your **actual** `CREATE TABLE` statement instead of describing it.

Comment: DROP TABLE IF EXISTS A;

CREATE TABLE `A` (
  `id` int unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `a` int unsigned NOT NULL,
  `b` int unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `c` int unsigned NOT NULL,
  `d` int unsigned NOT NULL,
  `response` varchar(5000) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

Comment: yeah but my actual one is-- create index idx_test on A(a,b,c,d,response);

Comment: We can't help you if you aren't giving us accurate details in your original posting.

Comment: Ok Dai plz give a solution for that query

Comment: We've already told you what the problem is in @lucumt's answer: you simply cannot create an `INDEX` over a set of columns that exceeds `3072` bytes, but your `response` column is `5000` bytes. There are alternative approaches you could use, but it would take me a long time to go through them all with no gurantee that you'd pay heed at all. I don't want to waste my life posting ignored advice to SO.

Comment: Just do `INDEX(a,b,c,d)` (without `response`).  `response` won't be useful any way because of "!=".

Comment: Ok Rick james  Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The error message has told your the reason.

Also in `MySQL` [Official Document](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-limits.html#:%7E:text=The%20index%20key%20prefix%20length,REDUNDANT%20or%20COMPACT%20row%20format.) we can find below description:

> - The index key prefix length limit is 3072 bytes for InnoDB tables that use DYNAMIC or COMPRESSED row format.
> - The index key prefix length limit is 767 bytes for InnoDB tables that use the REDUNDANT or COMPACT row format.

So the reason is obivious: **column `response` length is exceed the limit**

You need to reduce the size of `response`

Comment: is there any possibility to add index on those fields without any data type size changes or how to optimize the above select query

Comment: In my opinion,if you want to add index to such a big length variable,then `Elasticsearch` might be more suitable for you.Create index on big length column on mysql does not have meaningful usage